# Can two Eloquent ORM instances manipulate same DB table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've been working with PHP for years but have never really ventured out of procedural programming except when working with things like IPB and Magento. I'm trying to advance to the next level and get a better understanding of application structures, OOP, and some common PHP frameworks. That being said, I apologize if my question sounds immature or technically incorrect, I'm new to all of this.

Anyway, I was thinking about the structure of a simple forum. Forgetting about categories, tags, users, roles, advanced editors/bbcode, etc for now and just focusing on the topics and posts...

Because a topic is essentially a series of linked posts ordered by their `created_at` column, is there a necessity for an actual `topics` table or could one not simply have a `parent` column in the `posts` table? Topics would be identified as posts with a `parent` equal to their own `id`, `null` or `0`; something that would otherwise be unused.

If that were the db schema, how would it be laid out in the code, and if relevant, Laravel? Could you still create a `Topic` model? What would be the pros and cons to having two models working from a single table?

Lastly, how would you approach it if you were creating it? Would you use two tables? A pivot table? Something else? Please explain why you would implement it that way.

Comment: This isn't really a question about OOP or MVC, simply about database design

Comment: Both actually, it's a 2-part question. Asking what would be the best practice as far as database design and working/implementing it with an MVC framework such as Laravel goes.

Comment: @teresko Sorry, the question is not asking what you have updated the title with.

Comment: Emm .. no, it actually does.  What the question is **NOT** about is "Laravel Models, MVC Pattern".

Comment: @tereško Agreed, the OP's title is vague and could be better but your version suggests he will be creating two db connections and attempt to manipulate the same table concurrently. He's really looking for guidance as to how he should structure his database and how that translates into a laravel model.

Comment: He is trying to implement hierarchical structure and "two models manipulating same table" is how he described it .. an how other people at his level would describe it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the database design, self referencing tables are a valid design pattern and useful in cases of nested hierarchies such as Categories that can contain sub-categories that can also contain sub-categories ect ect... In this case sub-categories are categories that have a parent but there is no other distinction between them.

It's up to you to decide if a `Topic` and `Post` is an identical entity with a parent-child relationship. Personally the way I define the objects I don't feel they are.

The topic-post relationship you're describing is probably more of a One to Many relationship with the topic being the owner or maybe even a Many to Many relationship. This depends on the answer to, "can your topic have many posts? Can your posts be part of many topics?"

If you answered yes and no, then it is a One to Many with topics being the parent aka owner in the relationship.

If you answered yes and yes, then you have a Many to Many relationship. In SQL these are represented by a table with two columns that reference id's from two tables.

If you answered no and yes, then you have a One to Many with posts being the parent aka owner in the relationship.

In laravel, depending on the relationship, your models would include a method that looks like this:

**One to Many:**

```
class Topic extends Eloquent 
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

[Laravel One-to-Many Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many)

**Many to Many:**

In laravel the term "pivot table" refers to the table with references to the other objects.

```
class Post extends Eloquent 
{
    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Topic');
    }
}

class Topic extends Eloquent 
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Laravel [Many-to-Many](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many)

**Self referencing model:**

For a self referencing parent child relationship like I explained before you could create something like this, as you can see it's just a one-to-many and the many-to-one in the same model.

```
class Category extends Eloquent 
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

**There is also the Polymorphic Relation.**

This is useful when you have the same entity with just a different type. For example in this table you can have an insurance policy for an employee and a manager. The `personType` column in the `insurancePolicies` table defines who the insurance policy belongs to.

[image: Polymorphic relationship]

*Image from [codecommit.com](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/image-thumb.png)*

Our laravel models in this case would look like:

```
class InsurancePolicy extends Eloquent 
{
    public function insurable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Manager extends Eloquent 
{
    public function insurance()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('InsurancePolicy', 'person');
    }
}

class Employee extends Eloquent 
{
    public function insurance()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('InsurancePolicy', 'person');
    }
}
```

Most everything of what I've explained can also be found in the [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

Comment: Awesome, so in the instance where a topic hasMany posts and a post belongsTo a topic, is it possible to do it in a single table using a `parent_id` column? How would you create a Topic model from the posts table, is there a way to spoof or create a pseudo model to act as a collection of all related posts belonging to the same topic?

Comment: @user1960364 no you would create a table for topics and a table for posts. The posts table would have a column like `topic_id` which would reference back to the id of a topic in the `topic` table. Here is an example diagram of a [one to many relationship](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/media/22949/one-to-many_relationship.png) In this case `Customer` is the parent or the owner in the relationship, and `Order` is the child.

Comment: Then what did you mean when saying `The term Topic and Post is defined entirely by you, so if you're saying a topic is identical to a post and the relationship is actually hierarchical then yes by all means create a parent_id column and reference away.`?

Comment: @user1960364 What I mean is, since your the architect of the application the word "Topic" and the word "Post" is something you define. You could call them "Foos" and "Moos" which are meaningless words but you give them meaning. In your question it seems like your saying Topics and Posts are the same. Personally, I don't identify topics being equivalent to posts, but who am I to tell you how to identify objects in your application :). I guess put simply, I don't agree they are the same but if you feel they are; this is how you'd represent the data. Hope that made sense.

Comment: @user1960364 I reworked my answer and added some more stuff, hope it helps :).